# Password reset token is invalid or has been expired in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

It's me again asking for help in Nodejs. I tried processing the resetPassword function that I created on Nodejs using Postman but I kept having the same error. I also noticed from my MongoDB Compass that the resetPasswordToken on the database and the resetPasswordToken sent using mailtrap is not the same. Here are my codes:

```
//user.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const crypto = require('crypto')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
        maxLength: [30, 'Your name cannot exceed 30 characters']
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, ' Please enter your email'],
        unique: true,
        validate:[validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email address.']
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
        minlength: [6, 'Your password must be longer that 6 characters.'],
        select: false
    },
    role:{
        type: String,
        default: 'admin'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now
    },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpire: Date
})
//Encrypting password before saving user
userSchema.pre('save',async function(next){
    if(!this.isModified('password')){
        next()
    }
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)
})

//Compare user password
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function(enteredPassword){
    return await bcrypt.compare(enteredPassword, this.password)
}

//Return JWT token
userSchema.methods.getJwtToken = function(){
    return jwt.sign({id:this._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_TIME
    })
}
// Generate password reset token
userSchema.methods.getResetPasswordToken = function(){
    //Generate token
    const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

    //Hash and set to resetPasswordToken
    this.resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex')

    //Set token expire time
    this.resetpasswordExpire = Date.now() + 30 * 60 * 1000

    return resetToken
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```
//authController.js
const User = require('../models/user')

const ErrorHandler = require('../utils/errorHandler');
const catchAsyncErrors = require('../middlewares/catchAsynchErrors');
const sendToken = require('../utils/jwtToken');
const sendEmail = require('../utils/sendEmail')

const crypto = require('crypto')

//Register a user => /api/v1/register
exports.registerUser = catchAsyncErrors (async (req, res, next) =>{

    const { name, email, password } =req.body;

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password
    })

    sendToken(user, 200, res)
})

//Login User  => api/v1/login
exports.loginUser = catchAsyncErrors (async (req,res,next) =>{
    const { email, password} = req.body;

    //Checks if email and password is entered by user
    if(!email || !password){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Please enter email and password', 400))
    }
    //Finding the user in database
    const user = await User.findOne({email}).select('+password')

    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401));
    }

    //Checks if password or correct or not
    const isPasswordMatched = await user.comparePassword(password)

    if (!isPasswordMatched) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Invalid Email or Password', 401));
    }
    sendToken(user,200,res)
})
//Forgot Password => api/v1/password/forgot
exports.forgotPassword = catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, next) => {

    const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});

    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('User not found', 404));
    }
    //Get reset token
    const resetToken = user.getResetPasswordToken();

    await user.save({validateBeforeSave: false })

    //Create reset password url
    const resetUrl =`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/api/v1/password/reset/${resetToken}`;
    
    const message = `Your password reset token is as follows:\n\n${resetUrl}\n\n If you have not requested this email, then please ignore.`

    try{

        await sendEmail({
            email: user.email,
            subject: "KPOPStore Password Recovery",
            message
        })
        
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: `Email sent to ${user.email}`
        })
    }catch (error){
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

        await user.save({validateBeforeSave: false })

        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500))
 
    }
})
//ResetPassword => /api/v1/password/reset/:token
exports.resetPassword = catchAsyncErrors(async(req, res, next) =>{

    //Hash URL Token
    const resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(req.params.token).digest('hex')

    const user = await User.findOne({
        resetPasswordToken,
        resetPasswordExpire: { $gt: Date.now() }

    })
    if(!user){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Password reset token is invalid or has been expired.', 400)
        )
    }

    if(req.body.password !== req.body.confirmPassword){
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Password does not match', 400))
    }
    //Setup new password
    user.password = req.body.password;

    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

    await user.save();

    sendToken(user, 200, res)
})
//Logout user => /api/v1/logout
exports.logout = catchAsyncErrors(async (req,res,next)=>{
    res.cookie('token', null, {
        expires: new Date(Date.now()),
        httpOnly: true
    })
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Logged out'
    })
})
```

```
//jwtToken.js
//Create and send token and save in cookie.
const sendToken =( user, statusCode, res)=>{

    //Create Jwt token
    const token = user.getJwtToken();

    //Options for cookie
    const options = {
        expires: new Date(
            Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRES_TIME * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        ),
        httpOnly: true
    }

    res.status(statusCode).cookie('token', token, options).json({
        success: true,
        token,
        user
    })
}
module.exports = sendToken;
```

```
//auth.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { registerUser, loginUser, logout, forgotPassword, resetPassword} = require('../controllers/authController')

router.route('/register').post(registerUser);
router.route('/login').post(loginUser);

router.route('/password/forgot').post(forgotPassword)
router.route('/password/reset/:token').put(resetPassword)


router.route('/logout').get(logout);

    
module.exports = router;
```

I'm sorry for the long blocks of code. I've been stuck in this part for 3 days. Please help me again. Thank you!

Comment: The token in the DB and in the e-mailed link are not the same - you're saving the SHA-256 of the token in the DB, but you also send the hex value of the unhashed token via mail. Also, what does "having the same error" mean? You should specify the error that you're getting exactly - having it only in the title may not be helpful in the long run if you (or someone) decides to edit it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo in the User model's method:

```js
//Set token expire time
    this.resetpasswordExpire = Date.now() + 30 * 60 * 1000
```

It sets `resetpasswordExpire`, not `resetPasswordExpire`, so the change is not picked up by the Object-Document Mapper and not saved in the DB. Then, your search fails:

```js
User.findOne({
        resetPasswordToken,
        resetPasswordExpire: { $gt: Date.now() }

    })
```

because resetPasswordExpire is not set.

Comment: i might have overlooked that... thank you kind sir!!